# How to link to first/cover page or document title above automatically generated toc of Pandoc-generated document?

Tags: markdown, pandoc, epub, file-conversion, kindle

I'm using `--toc` for automatically generated table of contents during document conversion from `Markdown` to `EPUB` using `Pandoc` to publish in Amazon KDP.

I'd like to have reference in my document point to the first page `[⬆ Back to Top](#abc)` where `abc` would be link to the first/cover page.

Is it possible?

I tried `#`, `#toc`, `#link-to-title-name`, but it doesn't work.
Currently, I'm linking to the first element from the table of contents.
Solution to link to the document title, which is just above the automatically generated table of contents, would be even better.

Adding any extra heading in the document and linking to this isn't a solution, because it's being rendered below automatically generated table of contents = the same effect as linking to the first element from the table of contents.

If there's a way to render table of contents using `--toc` in specific location of a `Markdown` file, that would work as well.